# Timestamp filter for Sentry API for events

Tags: rest, sentry

I see that Sentry has an API to list the events in a project: https://docs.sentry.io/api/events/get-project-events/

But there doesn't seem to be any filter for start and end times here to get say, the events that occurred in the last one hour.

Is there any such filter available that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to first search by issues using https://docs.sentry.io/api/events/get-project-group-index/, and then get the latest event for each issue (if you need the level of detail) using https://docs.sentry.io/api/events/get-group-events-latest/

The first endpoint allows you to add `?query=` at the end to use the search queries you're used from the UI. You can filter by timerange over lastSeen there.

Comment: I know that this is not satisfactory. We're working on allowing you to jump to the event stream directly in the UI instead of having to jump from entity to entity. This will likely affect the API as well.

Comment: Any update on this? Im searching the API Docs and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

It is related to this feature request:

> Show only events which match filter in Issues screen. (also event &
>   user count)

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/15189